# A weird problem with long division algorithm contradicting division algorithm of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I was going through some precalculus concepts but suddenly I felt something's a bit weird and I am terribly confused . The function $f(x)=x^5-5x+2$ when divided by $5x^4-5$, and if we implement long division algorithm we get quotient as $\frac{x}{5}$ and remainder as $2-4x$. But we know by division algorithm of polynomials, $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$, $deg(r(x))<deg(g(x))$ . Also if we basically consider $q(x)$ as $g(x)$ and vice-versa  then we have $f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x)$ , but then we have,$deg(r(x))<deg(q(x))$. So, we can say, $deg(r(x))<min(deg(g(x),q(x)))$. But then, again, we get a contradiction by getting remainder as $2-4x$ in the example above as $deg(4x-2)\nless deg(\frac{x}{5})$. In fact, $deg(4x-2)=deg(\frac{x}{5})$. How is this possible ? I am not quite getting this...

Comment: The degree of the remainder has to be less than the degree of the divisor. There is no reason it should be less than the degree of the quotient. If you reverse the divisor and the quotient, you still have equality, but it's no longer the result of the division algorithm, as the remainder should likely have lower degree (here it would).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut But if we consider, the same polynomial $f(x)$, with the dividend as $q(x)$ , then we will get quotient as $g(x)$ and remainder as $r(x)$ , right? Then we have ,$deg(r(x))<deg(q(x))$. Thus, $$deg(r(x))<min(deg(q(x)),deg(g(x)))$$, isnt it?...

Comment: No. The unique quotient and remainder $q,r$ satisfy $a=bq+r$ **and** $\deg r<\deg b$. If you try to write the equality as being the division of $a$ by $q$, and $\deg r\ge \deg q$, it's not longer the result of the long division. Here the correct remainder would be a constant, as $q$ has degree $1$, and the quotient would not be $b$: you can still pull some terms from $r$ by subtracting multiples of $q$, so as to get a lower degree for the remainder.

Comment: divide $a=x^5-5x+2$ by $b=5x^4-5$, you get $a=bq+r$ with $q=x/5$ and $r=2-4x$ as you found. Divide $a$ by $q$, you get $a=qq'+r'$ with $q'=5x^4-25$ and $r'=2$. When you are doing the long division of $a$ by $b$, you have **never** $\deg r\ge\deg b$, but it's not a problem if you have $\deg r\ge\deg q$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That was a great help! But we got different remainders because it was a polynomial division , correct? If it was a division over integers then we would have got the same remainder, using Euclid's division algorithm,  right? Due to which $r<min(b,q)$

Comment: No, it's the same problem: with integers (positive to make things simpler) you would have $a=bq+r$ and $r<b$, but it's certainly possible to have $r\ge q$, while if you divide $a$ by $q$, the new remainder will still be lower than $q$.

Comment: Intuitively, in both cases (polynomial or integers), you are subtracting multiples of $b$ from $a$, until it's not possible any longer, and the remainder is what's left. If $\deg r\ge b$ (polynomial) or $r\ge b$ (integer), then you can still subtract something from $r$, so you are not done. Therefore $\deg r<\deg b$ and $r<b$ respectively. But it says nothing about $q$ vs $r$. You may very well have $q=0$ (if $\deg b>\deg a$, resp. $b>a$) and then $r=a$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you so much! So the total thing depends upon the "thing" which we consider as the "divisor" as the division algorithms , be it for polynomials or integers , it gives a "unique" quotient and remainder depending upon the divisor  .  For example , $17=6.2+5$ and $17=2.8+1$ , in both cases we get a unique ordered pair of $(\text{quotient},\text{remainder})$,correct?

Comment: If you mean resp. $17$ divided by $6$ and $17$ divided by $2$, then yes. And yes, the result depends on what is considered the divisor, because two conditions must be satisfied: $a=bq+r$ **and** $r<b$ (or $\deg r<\deg b$ for polynomials). And these two conditions make $q$ and $r$ unique. If only one of those two conditions is satisfied, it's not what we call the euclidean division.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what do you mean by the last line "If you have only one, it's not what we call the euclidean division."? I did not get this...

Comment: If you have only $a=bq+r$ and not $b<r$ or only $b<r$ and not $a=bq+r$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I get the whole point but shouldn't it be $r<b$...

Comment: Argh! :o) Yes of course.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much ! I do get it now...